# continuity of a function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis

How can I show that a function satisfying $|f(x)-f(y)| \leq |x^{2}-y^{2}|$ for all $x,y \in\mathbb{R}$ is continuous with an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof?

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Factor the right hand side and use a little _max_ trick for $\epsilon $.

Comment: be careful that you need to fix $x$ or $y$ first and then $\varepsilon>0$ so that you can obtain $\delta>0$ by factoring the right hand side of the inequality.

Hint : consider $x$ and $y$ to be "close" with each other so you can assume $|x-y|<1$ for instance.

Comment: I had split it up into |x-y||x+y| but I was stuck on how to relate $\epsilon$ to $\delta$ through |x-y|

Answer (score 1):

For some fixed point $y$, we have $\vert f(x)-f(y) \vert \le \vert x^2-y^2 \vert=\vert x-y \vert \vert x+y \vert$

Suppose $\vert x-y \vert \lt 1 \Rightarrow \vert x \vert \lt \vert y \vert + 1$

But $\vert x+y \vert \le \vert x \vert + \vert y \vert$

Thus, $\vert x-y \vert \vert x+y \vert \lt   (2 \vert y \vert +1) \vert x-y \vert$

Now, let $\delta = min\{1,{\varepsilon \over 2 \vert y \vert +1}\}$, and we have $\vert x^2-y^2\vert \lt \varepsilon$

Answer (score 0):

using direct proof

that f is continuous at a point $x_0$:

$(\forall) \epsilon \gt 0 (\exists) \delta \gt 0: \mid x-x
_0\mid \lt \delta\Rightarrow \mid{f(x)-f(x_0)}\mid\lt \epsilon$

but $\mid{f(x)-f(x_0)}\mid\lt\mid{x^2-x_0^2}\mid$

therefore the continuity is confirmed if:

$(\forall) \epsilon \gt 0 (\exists) \delta \gt 0: \mid x-x
_0\mid \lt \delta\Rightarrow \mid{x^2-x_0^2}\mid\lt \epsilon$

lets solve for $\delta$:

$\mid{x^2-x_0^2}\mid\lt\mid{x+x_0}\mid\cdot \delta\lt (\mid x\mid +\mid{x_0}\mid)\cdot \delta\lt (2\cdot \mid{x_0}\mid+\delta)\cdot \delta$

therefore if $\delta$ solves $(2\cdot \mid{x_0}\mid+\delta)\cdot \delta=\epsilon$, the continuity of $f(x)$ at $x_0$ is confirmed

solving the quadratic, using the quadratic formula I picked $\delta = \sqrt{x_0^2+\epsilon}-\mid{x_0}\mid$

now to conclude:

$(\forall) \epsilon \gt 0, (\exists) \delta \gt 0, \delta = \sqrt{x_0^2+\epsilon}-x_0: \mid{x-x_0}\mid\lt\delta\Rightarrow \mid{f(x)-f(x_0)}\mid\lt\mid{x^2-x_0^2}\mid\lt\epsilon (\therefore)$